# How to automatically push tag to git after npm version command?

Tags: shell, npm

[`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version):

> Run this in a package directory to bump the version and write the new data back to package.json [..] If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag.

How do I configure npm/ wrap `npm version` command to automatically push tag to git?, i.e. an equivalent of:

```sh
npm version patch
+ foo@3.0.1
git push origin v3.0.1
```

NPM documentation recommends adding a [`postversion` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to the `prackage.json`, e.g.

```json
"scripts": {
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags && rm -rf build/temp"
}
```

However, this suggestion applies to a single package only and it is bad because it syncs all the tags, not just the last created tag.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the new tag is the only tag on the current revision something like this might work.

```
$ npm version patch
$ tag=$(git tag --points-at HEAD)
$ git push origin "$tag"
```

Otherwise you could try catching (and parsing) the output from `npm version patch` like this perhaps (assuming the output is always `+ foo@3.0.1` and the tag is always `v<part after @`).

```
$ tag=$(npm version patch 2>&1)
$ tag=v${tag#*@}
$ git push origin "$tag"
```

You could also try grabbing the available tags before the `npm version patch` call and then diffing that list against the available tags after which should find the new tag and you can push it.